# locate element in protractor from multiline text

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor

I have few webElements, which when converted to text return:

```
School, Primary School\n' +
Church, Catholic Church,

FireStation, Primary Station\n' +
Church, Catholic Church,

School, Primary School\n' +
FireStation, Primary Station,
```

They need to be located by 2 separate conditions, but I am unable to chain them.
I am trying to locate the first element from list

```
School, Primary School\n' +
Church, Catholic Church,
```

by using:

```
element(by.cssContainingText('.given_class',`${interpolation[for_school]}`, `${interpolation[for_church]}`)).getText()
```

Nothing works. I have tried chaining locators

```
element(by.cssContainingText('.given_class',`${interpolation[for_school]}`)).element(by......`)).getText()
```

no luck

I have tried using few other methods, but nothing seems to work.

They all have the same class, id, type etc. They need to be found by text

Answer (score 1):

use xpath `and` operator

```
element(by.xpath('//*[contains(text(),"locate element") and contains(text(),"from multiline text")]'))
```

you can try it on this page to locate questions header `//*[contains(text(),"locate element") and contains(text(),"from multiline text")]`